# versionCode/versionName bug

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this strange problem with my android studio, when I try to compile/run/build apk the androidCode and androidName always comes to version 1.0, no matter what I set it. I've been changing the main AndroidManifest.xml file, and still nothing. Does anyone else have this bug, or what have you done to fix it?

Comment: Does your build.gradle have rules that override versionCode/versionName?

Comment: Yes, that was the culprit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was build.gradle being the culprit, under android, you need to change the settings here:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 2 <----This
    versionName "1.1" <----This
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the **android:versionCode** and **android:versionName** in AndroidManifest, as shown below:

If Old is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hello"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hello"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
```

Comment: @LalitPoptani: Thanks for the correction, it was a typo, edited answer

Comment: It is not for Android stuio.